# Did S. Lang prove Kuratowski–Zorn lemma without Axiom of choice or Well-ordering theorem?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

In S. Lang' [Algebra](https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/algebra-serge-lang.pdf), Appendix 2, the author proved [Zorn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). After a carefully reading of the proof, I failed to see either Axiom of choice or Well-ordering theorem were assumed in his proof. So did he use any equivalent forms of Zorn's Lemma to prove it at all? If not, can Zorn's Lemma be proven (as Lang did) using other axioms of set theory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice and to the Well-Ordering Theorem. You cannot prove one of these statements without assuming another (Lang alludes to this on page 881). At a brief glance, it seems that Lang uses the Axiom of Choice on page 884, in the proof of Corollary 2.4. There, he constructs a function $f : A \to A$ by choosing, for each $x \in A$, an element $y_x \in A$ such that $y_x > x$. This is precisely an application of the axiom of choice! To be more explicit, he is making use of the existence of a choice function $A \to \coprod_{x \in A} \{y \in A : y > x\}$.

Comment: Thank you! I wish Lang had mentioned the usage of Axiom of Choice more explicitly.